# IIS web server on a Domain can't run ASP.NET application

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have my web server on a domain and everything is fine until I try to browse to site.

I have given the `DOMAIN\MACHINE$` rights to the virtual directory and the app pool identity is `Network Service`.

I get this error when I test these settings:

> The server is configured to use
>   pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the
>   specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the
>   built-in account has access. Make sure
>   that the application pool identity has
>   Read access to the physical path. If
>   this server is joined to a domain, and
>   the application pool identity is
>   NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that domain\computer_name$ has Read
>   access to the physical path. Then test
>   these settings again

Comment: Is the virtual directory pointing to a directory hosted on another server?

Comment: no. the sql server is on another computer in domain. so instead of Network service i enter Domain\LOCALMACHINE$ but still get error

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a delegation issue.  I would first enable kernel mode authentication, then make sure that the computer account is trusted for delegation

Comment: how exactly to do that

Comment: Here's an article regfering to the certificate services buthe the way delegation is configured is exactlythe same:  http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2009/04/22/how-to-configure-the-windows-server-2008-ca-web-enrollment-proxy.aspx